# Can't connect to socket on ejs file, reference and io not defined error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, ejs

I need to send data to my `express` app when I make a socket connection on the client side using `socket.io`. However, I get a reference error on the below **active.ejs** file when I try to do this. However, I am successfully connected to the socket, because the socket-id is logged to my console in index.js (which is also where I need to send the `user_info` data)

This is the client side html(ejs) page - **active.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Active</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:4000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Welcome,
      <%= user_info.uri %>
    </p>
    // REFERENCE ERROR HERE
    // changing {query: user_info} to just user_info doesn't help either
    <% var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000/tune-in', {query: user_info}); %> 
  </body>
</html>
```

This is how the `user_info` object is passed from **controller.js** to the above html(ejs) file **active.ejs**

```
  app.get('/tune-in', function(req, res){
    res.render('active', {user_info: user_data});
  });
```

I need to send the `user_info` from **active.ejs** to **index.js**
Here's the relevant **index.js**

```
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4000);
console.log("Listening to port 4000...");
var io = socket(server);
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  // The below log executes and displays a socket id.
  console.log('Made socket connection', socket.id);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access `user_info` the way you currently are. Simply change this line

```
<% var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000/tune-in', {query: user_info}); %>
```

to

```
<% var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000/tune-in', {query: "<%= user_info %>"}); %>
```

Comment: For some reason, I'm now getting the following error - `Error: Could not find matching close tag for "<%", pointing to no specific line.

Comment: Hm try putting that piece of code in a `<script>` tag instead of using that. So something like this. `<script> var socket =........ </script>` @Kek